# Toad: Count characters in SQL statement

Tags: toad, maximo, charactercount

*Toad for Oracle 12:*

[I'm working in a system](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/mam/7.6.1.2?topic=SSLKT6_7.6.1.2/com.ibm.mam.doc/pdf_mam_qsg.html) that has an unfortunate limitation where an SQL query's FROM clause can only have up to 1000 characters (including spaces). This becomes a problem when the FROM clause has a lengthy subquery in it (> 1000 chars).

So, when writing SQL in Toad, I need a way to highlight the SQL in the FROM clause and count the characters in the highlighted text, including spaces.

Currently, I copy the text into MS Word and do a character count there. That works, but it would be better if I could do the character count right in Toad.

---

Question:

Does Toad 12 have SQL character count functionality?

Comment: That is ridiculous to have such a limit.  Sorry.

Comment: It has that functionality. Look at the bottom left panel of the status bar when you highlight text in the SQL editor window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @SamM mentioned, the bottom panel/status bar shows the character count when I highlight text in the SQL editor window:

[image]